# Download all package versions with aptly

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt, package-management, aptly

How can we download all versions of a package when mirroring ? 
An example is the scsi-modules which can be found here: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/ i need them all mirrored yet aptly is only downloading the latest.

Documentation does not include any option for this as far as i can see.

Answer (score 0):

aptly is downloading every package version which is included into `Packages` index, which exactly matches `apt` behavior. If you need to download all the versions, you can download all the package files to some temp dir, and import then into aptly local repo.

Comment: That does not seem to be correct or i am doing something wrong. I have a trusty-main mirroring the ubuntu trusty repos and this package is not being mirrored: https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/scsi-modules-3.13.0-100-generic-di 

which is present on http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/debian-installer/binary-amd64/Packages.gz any idea ?

Comment: @Onitlikesonic do you have steps to reproduce this issue?